# wordpress site navigation

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using following code to display my 3 level menu:

```
if(!$post->post_parent){
   // will display the subpages of this top level page
   $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
}else{
    // diplays only the subpages of parent level
   //$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");

   if($post->ancestors) {
        // now you can get the the top ID of this page
        // wp is putting the ids DESC, thats why the top level ID is the last one
        $ancestors = end($post->ancestors);
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$ancestors."&echo=0");
        // you will always get the whole subpages list
    }
}

if ($children) { ?>
    <ul id="submenu">
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

It lists pages in side bar, second level then 3rd level too. I would like to include very top level too so i would like to my structure to look as follow:

```
*A
 -a
  --a
 -b
  --b
 -c
  --c
```

Where as above code is not listing main page i.e. *A, i hope that make sense and someone will be able to help

Thanks,

Comment: Could you clarify?  If you're on page --a, what do you want showing in the sidebar?  And if you're on page -b, what do you want showing in the sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this code snippet](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_current_Page.2C_ancestors_of_current_page.2C_and_children_of_current_page) at the [wordpress codex site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page), and I think it's exactly what you're looking for, I've pasted it in for convenience:

```
<?php
//if the post has a parent
if($post->post_parent){
  //collect ancestor pages
  $relations = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
  //get child pages
  $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = $post->ID AND post_type='page'" );
  if ($result){
    foreach($result as $pageID){
      array_push($relations, $pageID->ID);
    }
  }
  //add current post to pages
  array_push($relations, $post->ID); // <---- THIS IS INCLUDING THE PARENT
  //get comma delimited list of children and parents and self
  $relations_string = implode(",",$relations);
  //use include to list only the collected pages. 
  $sidelinks = wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&include=".$relations_string);
}else{
  // display only main level and children
  $sidelinks = wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&depth=2&child_of=".$post->ID);
}

if ($sidelinks) { ?>
  <h2><?php the_title() ;?></h2>
  <ul>
    //links in <li> tags
    <?php echo $sidelinks; ?>
  </ul>         
<?php } ?>
```

It also has some built-in logic to not display everything if this is a highest-level page.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Nearly, however its not showing 3rd level when i'm at top page.
So following my example logic When I'm on *A its only showing
-a
-b
-c

and when i'm at -a its only showing 
*A 
  -a 
   --a

Comment: @jmysona all you have to do then is change the depth.  If you look at the line in the `else` clause, just change it to: `wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&depth=2&child_of=".$post->ID);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="breadcrumbs">
  <a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="">Home</a>
  <?php
    $parent_id  = $post->post_parent;
    $breadcrumbs = array();
    while ($parent_id) {
      $page = get_page($parent_id);
      $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="'.get_permalink($page->ID).'" title="">'.get_the_title($page->ID).'</a>';
      $parent_id  = $page->post_parent;
    }
    $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
    foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb) echo ' / '.$crumb;
  ?>
</div>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

credit : Ivovic
from : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-page-parent-on-page-with-title?replies=13